# Changing default folder location in MVC project folder structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, directory

Is there any way to set default Contents location in different path or using different name instead of Contents?

Edit: 
Thus, I can download bootstrap or something else from nuget which are related with Content folder into the new directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever name you like. Just rename the folder and update your `BundleConfig` to reflect the new name:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/SomeOtherName/css").Include(
            "~/SomeOtherName/bootstrap.css",
            "~/SomeOtherName/site.css"));
```

And in the `_Layout.cshtml` make sure to include the correct name:

```
@Styles.Render("~/SomeOtherName/css")
```

Comment: But do you think this will change the default location for nuget packages when I wanted to download?

Comment: No, this is unrelated to nuget packages.